# Get value for specific keys in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch data from Firebase with the keys of an array. How do I do this?

My Firebase Database Structure looks like this.

[image: Firebase Database structure:]

I want to get the post for the keys at "LOCATIONS" only. So I store the keys in locations in an array:

```
var nearbyPosts = [-L-9P7oUUs40qJLFSNyt, -L-9YwHX-RKZFIiyZ7sG]
```

The problem is, how do I get data from posts using the keys in this array? or is there any other way to do it?

I have tried different attempts of querying like:

```
let dbRef = DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.queryEqual(toValue: nearbyPosts).queryOrderedByKey()
```

or

```
let dbRef = DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.queryStarting(atValue: nearbyPosts.startIndex).queryEnding(atValue: nearbyPosts.endIndex).queryOrderedByKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure exactly what you mean by locations but when I want to retrieve data at a specific locations I do it like this:

```
Database.database().reference().child("posts/\(ourID!)/comment").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

For clarification: 'Posts' is the branch that everything is published under.
'ourID' is the specific post, posted by a user.
'Comment' is the data in the post.

See, Posts is everything. The long string is my posts, and comment is a value inside of the post that I am reading from. The long string in your case, would be 'LOCATIONS'. Hope this helps.

```
Posts:
    4TBxDgN1Q4I4KNpp4
        Comment = "" 
        Date = "2017-11-29 01:51:31 +0000"
        Post = "This is an example post"
        User = "JDerbs"
```

Comment: The problem is that I want "ourID" in your example to be the whole array of nearbyPosts, so I dont have to get one post at the time. 
I kind of want this: Database.database().reference().child("posts/\(nearbyPosts)/comment"), but it wont let me do that.
Struggling to explain but hope you understand.

Comment: Well that's what I would do...What type of error. If it was me I would create an array up top like whatever you want to call it. Then:        var posts:[String] = []      
Database.database().reference().child("posts/nearbyPosts").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("***\(snapshot)")
            if let item = snapshot.value as? String{
               self.posts.append(item)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })     See where it says comments.append? That's where you add the post to the array you get the snapshot of data.

Comment: let dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(nearbyPosts) 
reults in the error: "Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'"
Also tried using .child("\(nearbyPosts)") and .child("posts/nearbyPosts") but those results in error with no explanation. I forgot to tell that I don't need the "comments" part. I want the whole posts.

Comment: Did you forget the quotes in .child(nearbyPosts). Idk if that's a typo of not but thought I might as well point it out. Also, you're referencing 'nearbyPosts' as something from the database. If it's not something from the database, I would delete the .child(nearbyPosts) since it's not in the database.